# VisualStudio 2017 typescript breakpoints not getting hit

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

I am adding features to an existing  angular2  app built using asp.net core 1.1 template on VisualStudio 2017 . Typescript and Webpack are being used . Source map is enabled on webpack config . I am able to debug the Typescript code on browser(chrome  dev tools) but Typescript breakpoints are not getting hit on VisualStudio 2017. It says symbols are not loaded . I have also enabled script debugging in VisualStudio. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it break if try to reload the page? I have experienced prolems on VS Code that breakpoints does not on initial run, but after reload a page those are working correctly. How is your devtool configured in the webpack config?

Comment: Im using visualstudio2017 and not VsCode. It is neither working on first load nor on page reload.Yes devtool is configured on webpack config.

Comment: @jaycyborg, Do you enable the Microsoft Symbol server under Tools->Options->Symbols? Whether all Angular 2 apps have this issue or just the specific one? Which browser did you use? How about using different browser? Of course, please make sure that you add the breakpoint firstly before you hit F5. Other members reported the kind of issue before:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/189019/breakpoints-not-hit-in-typescript-using-chrome.html and https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/125941/typescript-debugging-is-not-working-on-visual-stud.html.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Yes Microsoft symbol server option is enabled, I even tried with another angular test app and results are same , break points are not getting hit. I have tried all the suggestions mentioned in the post shared by you ,still I don't see it working. It says symbols are not loaded. Let me know if I have to check another options. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jaycyborg,Do you use the Chrome as the default browser? Do you enable the option "Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE)" under TOOLS->Options->Debugging? If still no help, please share a simple sample to one drive, I will download and repro it in my side using the same Environment as yours.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT I tried with Chrome,Edge and IE as default browser.Yes debugging is enabled under Tools->options.This is a huge code base and cannot be shared due to NDA that I have signed.I will try to build similar trimmed down version of the code structure and will share you.

Comment: @jaycyborg, It would be better if you could share a simple sample, of course, please also tell me the code line where you add the breakpoint if you could share the code here:)